# Flutter on Mac unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android, macos, flutter, gradle

I have a Flutter project on an old laptop and exactly the same on an MacBook air 2017.

But on the MacBook I always get the following Error;

```
 Building with sound null safety 

                                                                        
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                                
                                                                        
* What went wrong:                                                      
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.                  
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.       
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1.            
     Required by:                                                       
         project :                                                      
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1.         
         > Could not get resource 'http://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.1/gradle-4.2.1.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.2.1/gradle-4.2.1.pom'.
               > PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
                                                                        
* Try:                                                                  
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
                                                                        
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                        
BUILD FAILED in 2s
```

I tried to

- reinstall Flutter
- disable proxy in system settings (I had no proxy configuaration in a gradle file)
- to download the certificate and add it to Android Studio

But nothing works.

my project level build.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://maven.google.com"}
        maven { url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"}
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

and `flutter doctor -v`

```
✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on macOS 11.2.1 20D75 darwin-x64, locale fr-FR)
    • Flutter version 2.2.2 at /Users/*************/Documents/Silas/flutter
    • Framework revision d79295af24 (il y a 3 semaines), 2021-06-11 08:56:01 -0700
    • Engine revision 91c9fc8fe0
    • Dart version 2.13.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/*************/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.23.0

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Chrome (web) • chrome • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114

• No issues found!
```

I hope you can help me because I already spend a lot of time on this error.

Thanks

Comment: Did you every figure out the issue?

Comment: @AlexSullivan No, but I tested the same project on two different Imacs and I d'ont have this issue.